# Iterating array of array in swift using map

Tags: swift, maps, reduce

I am trying to udnerstand the concept of map function in swift. I want to iterate an array of array in such a way that I can print each element in every array along with it's index.
Below is my code

```
var raceResults = [["one","two","four"],["two","one","five","six"],["two","one","four","ten"],["one","two","four"]]

   raceResults.map {
        return $0 // Returns first array 
    }.map { 
        print($0) // was expecting each element in first array here but it's whole array 
    }
```

I am wondering how can I get hold over every single element in array using chaining ?

Comment: Is the `.` in `$0.` a typo, or did you intend for it to be there?

Comment: Corrected. Was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a single array, like:

```
let raceResult = ["one", "two", "four"]
```

If we want to combine each element with an offset counting from `0`, we can use [`Array.enumerated()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/enumerated()), along with `map`.

```
let numberedRaceResult = raceResult
    .enumerated()
    .map { offset, element in "\(offset). \(element)" }

for numberedResult in numberedRaceResult {
    print(numberedResult)
}

// Prints:
// 0. one
// 1. two
// 2. four
```

You can see that I didn't call `print` inside the closure passed to `map`. You *can* do this, but it kind of defeats the purpose of `map` (which is to create an equal-sized output array from the transformed elements of the input array), because the result would be unused. In that case, it makes more sense to just use a `for` loop or a call to `forEach`, like @Sh_Khan showed.

To handle a nested array, it's much the same. We can use the same logic as for one array, but apply it to each sub-array.

```swift
let raceResults = [
    ["one", "two", "four"],
    ["two", "one", "five", "six"],
    ["two", "one", "four", "ten"],
    ["one", "two", "four"],
]

let numberedRaceResults = raceResults
    .enumerated()
    .flatMap { outterOffset, raceResult in
        raceResult
            .enumerated()
            .map { innerOffset, element in "\(outterOffset).\(innerOffset). \(element)" }
    }

for numberedResult in numberedRaceResults {
    print(numberedResult)
}

// Prints:
// 0.0. one
// 0.1. two
// 0.2. four
// 1.0. two
// 1.1. one
// 1.2. five
// 1.3. six
// 2.0. two
// 2.1. one
// 2.2. four
// 2.3. ten
// 3.0. one
// 3.1. two
// 3.2. four
```

You'll notice that I used `flatMap` on the outter array, instead of a simple `map`. You can change it back and forth and compare the result. In short, `flatMap` gives you a single flat array of string results, rather than an array of sub-arrays of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Map is used to convert one bunch of type T into things of some other type, X.  Like map these Ints to String?s.  **You should not use map for side-effects**, like printing the values, or updating a database etc.  It should be a *pure function* that takes an input and returns an output.  "Map these A's into B's". Pure meaning the value of the function only depends on the input, nothing else like the current state of the world, and doesn't change the world either (like printing to the console), so for example, map these int's by the function that adds 2 to them.

In your example:

```
var raceResults = [["one","two","four"],["two","one","five","six"],["two","one","four","ten"],["one","two","four"]]
```

You have an array of "arrays of strings".

You can map that to an array of  so long as you have a function that takes "array of string" and turns that into "something else"

Here you map it with the *Identity function*, the function that just returns its input, which is going to take an array of strings as input and return the exact same array of strings as output:

```
   raceResults.map {
       return $0 // Returns first array 
   }
```

This does nothing, and the result is the exact same thing as raceResults.

If you want to iterate over all these elements then the function **flatMap** is handy:

```
raceResults.flatMap { $0 }.forEach { print($0) }
```

`flatMap` is flatten, then map.  Flattening an array of arrays is to return an array with all the things 'flattened' one level, so [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], but the definition of what to flatten means depends on the type of container, for example flatMap on Optional means something else to flatMap on Array.